# Individual Anjaneya photo

Tags: scripture, belief, puranas, hanuman

Many people say that we should not keep individual Anjaneya photo in our house for worship. He should always be with Lord Rama, Sita and Lakshmana. Any evidence from age old puranas or scriptures supporting this sentence?

Comment: An opinion - till the camera made it to India, I am sure the Indians and their forefathers used metal/clay etc. idols for worship at homes etc. Now it is believed that an appropriate metal statue stores the energy when you worship it ! 
Anjaneya is a celibate, having high calibre and immense knowledge of the 64 arts and so on. He is an ascetic more or less and a symbol of strength, sacrifice and selflessness. To host and worship such a god requires a similar lifestyle which is impossible for a family. Not in the house but at the entrance or the village entry, Anjaneya can be found

Comment: @KA--He can take a small roop also. In samudra he entered in the mouth of a rakshashi and came out in few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing like that, there is a belief in North India that if anyone worships Sri Hanuman than that person gets the blessings from Sri Ram too.It was one of the boon Sri Ram gave to Sri Hanuman.

[image: Ranjit Hanuman Mandir,Indore(M.P)]

This temple is very famous in Indore a city in Madhya Pradesh.

Comment: @CM---But in south there prevails a saying like this. Hence I asked. This is not an answer put ur views in comment. Give sources when you answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Sorry I am not having any literary source to back it,but that is what I have seen since childhood.

Comment: @CM-Nice 2 share the photo-I had a good darshan by sitting in front of the system. But the community wants the source for answer.

Comment: You should cite sources. You are not providing sources in any of your answers. Pls. do so Or they will be flagged as inappropriate.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar source for this answer can not be provided as it is a custom which is in practised from generations